# Creating Table Views Based off an Array with Swift

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift, tableview, swift2

Is there a way that would allow me to create tables within a view controller and then position them? I have an array "items" that would output the total amount of TableViews -1. So for instance if the array "items" contained 15 items, 14 TableViews would be created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you add *n* `tableView`s to a single view controller?  Yes, but it's not practical or reasonable to write the amount of code you'd need to manage a varying number of layouts and delegates.

A `tableView` is designed to scroll (sections or) rows of cells, not to show a single item on screen.  If you are determined to layout each item, you would be better off using a (much lighter) custom `view` instead of a `tableView`.

However, a single `UICollectionView` *can* do what you want to do.  Yes, you'd have to write some code to manage the flow layout, depending on the number of brackets it had to display, but you could easily manage a grid-based approach with each column (round) showing teams and score.

This would certainly be more intuitive and practical to have a single scrollable region, where each bracket is able be selected and interacted with, instead of trying to add multiple tableViews to a view (controller).